# Select Xpath of button

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The following inspect code i have is to click the button  I can confirm my order

```
<button type="submit" class="button btn btn-default button-medium">
                <span>I confirm my order<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>
</button>
<span>I confirm my order<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>
```

The one I've tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'I confirm my order')]\"")).click();
```

The error is coming out using Eclipse as IDE for Selenium Testing stated below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(text(),'I confirm my order')]" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text(),'I confirm my order')]"' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]/span[1]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The text **I confirm my order** is within the child `<span>` of the `<button>` element. So, to `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.btn.btn-default.button-medium > span i.icon-chevron-right.right")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='button btn btn-default button-medium'][./span[contains(., 'I confirm my order')]]")).click();
  ```

However, as the element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.button.btn.btn-default.button-medium > span i.icon-chevron-right.right"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='button btn btn-default button-medium'][./span[contains(., 'I confirm my order')]]"))).click();
  ```